# Self documenting LWC components

Tags: lightning-web-components, documentation, jsdoc

I would like our lightning web components to self document on confluence. Kind of like javadocs for LWC. One idea I was thinking about was to have a nightly job that runs and uses JSDoc (https://jsdoc.app/) to parse the comments in the JS file and export them in a documentation folder somewhere which are later imported into confluence using the confluence CLI. Is there a better way to do this that someone here may point me towards? Thanks

Comment: I entirely agree with using JSDoc, as covered in [this answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/303684/how-to-document-lightning-web-components-lwcs/303693#303693). How you get it into confluence is beyond the scope of this forum, IMHO.

Comment: This may not meet your needs exactly, but Lightning components are already self-documenting to an extent, provided developers are being detailed with your components. You can see your component library by going here: _https://<your-domain>.lightning.force.com/docs/component-library_

Comment: Just to follow up on my last comment, it looks like LWC don't get documented in that manner _yet_, [per Salesforce](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/get_started_component_library): _Documentation for Lightning web components developed in your org isn’t yet supported
The Component Reference doesn’t display documentation for your custom Lightning web components._

With that limitation in mind, I think a tool like JSDoc is perfect for the job. But the nuances of building something that uses that, I think, is outside the scope of this StackExchange.

Comment: That doesn't work well for off-org documentation, of course. For example, documentation you provide to (potential) customers when you are an ISV that provides an App on the AppExchange. I'm also not sure how you actually set up the "definition" for a LWC.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback guys

Comment: FYI, I have heard that such a tool is being developed, but we likely won't get to see it as customers until 2021.

Comment: still no updates, right?

Comment: @sfdcfox - any word on the tool that's getting developed?

Comment: @PartOfTheOhana I haven't heard of it recently, but fingers crossed. It'd be very nice to have.